# C++ Pig Latin is not working

Tags: c++

So, I have tried and tried to make this c++ pig latin program, but it's just not working. Here is my code:

```
int main()
{
string tmp = "";
char a;

cout << "String: "; getline(cin, tmp);

char pigLatin[1024];
strncpy(pigLatin, tmp.c_str(), sizeof(pigLatin));
pigLatin[sizeof(pigLatin) - 1] = 0;

a = pigLatin[0];
pigLatin[sizeof(pigLatin)] = '-';
pigLatin[sizeof(pigLatin) + 1] = a;
pigLatin[sizeof(pigLatin) + 2] = 'a';
pigLatin[sizeof(pigLatin) + 3] = 'y';

for (int i = 1; i < sizeof(pigLatin); i++)
{
    cout << pigLatin[i];
}
cout << endl;
system("PAUSE");

return 0;
}
```

When I run it, it doesn't return any runtime errors or anything, but when I enter a string it just puts the string minus the first letter and then a bunch of spaces. Does anyone know the problem?

Comment: `sizeof` is _not_ doing what you think it does.

Comment: I see your problem: you are using the wrong entry point.  You should be using `ainmay`.

Comment: It looks like you need a C++ book. Start at the beginning, do all the exercises.

Comment: @ZanLynx Well I do use an app for learning c++ and I believe I am around when you start learning about data structures and things of that nature and it seemed like this would be an easy project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `sizeof` returns the size in bytes of the array not the length of the string it contains. In this case the result of `sizeof` is 1024 assuming `char` is 8 bits. You could always use `strlen` to determine the length of the string or you can eliminate the use of a naked array altogether and use `std::string` instead. This would decrease the size of your code significantly. Something like this...

```
int main()
{
    cout << "String: " << flush;
    string pigLatin;
    getline(cin, pigLatin);

    pigLatin += '-';
    pigLatin += pigLatin[0];
    pigLatin += "ay";
    pigLatin.erase(0, 1);

    cout << pigLatin << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: Yes, this would work with more ease, but it still prints the first letter of pigLatin. But I assume I can just make a for statement that will print starting with pigLatin[i], yes?